# Website Fading Effect not Working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

For some reason, my website's fading & positioning work and look great in Chrome & Firefox but Internet Explorer is not showing the fading effect at all and the alignment is all messed up. here's the coding:

```
    /* fade slider */
.slides {
    height:600px;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
}
.slides ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}

/* keyframes #anim_slides */
@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}


@keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
.slides ul li {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;

    /* css3 animation */
    -webkit-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -moz-animation-duration: 24.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

   animation-name: anim_slides;
   animation-duration: 24.0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-delay: 0;
   animation-play-state: running;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/* css3 delays */
.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6.0s;
animation-delay: 6.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(3), .slides ul  li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12.0s;
animation-delay: 12.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(4), .slides ul  li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18.0s;
   -moz-animation-delay: 18.0s;
animation-delay: 18.0s;
}


.slides ul  li:nth-child(5), .slides ul  li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24.0s;
animation-delay: 24.0s;
}

.slides ul li img {
    display:block;
}

/* keyframes #anim_titles */
@-webkit-keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

@keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        left:10%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

and you can check out the html coding for positioning by checking out the website- http://metroanimalshelter.org/

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are only including the `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixed CSS properties, which will only work in webkit and mozilla browsers respectively. In every place you include the prefixes, you need to also include an unprefixed property. For example:

```
.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6.0s;
    animation-delay: 6.0s;
}
```

It's also worth noting that this will only work in IE10 and 11. Versions of IE before that did not support CSS animations. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Thanks Steve; I provided an update below if you could check it out; something must still not be right.

Comment: thanks again Steve; sorry for posting it in the wrong spot. I updated the coding above; it's still not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MikeS still a little bit off, everywhere you have `@-keyframes` it should be `@keyframes`. Everything else looks good.

Comment: Thank you Steve; above is the current version and it's still not working in IE 10.

Comment: Finally got it working; how stupid of me, I was sooo focused on the css side; I completely forgot to look at one important little spot in the html side. It was set for IE=7 rather than the newest version. After i switched it to IE=11 it works in IE :) thanks for your help Steve.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use autoprefixer instead set up vendor prefixes for every browser.
Less to write and easy to maintain your code

https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer